# How can I check if a user has permissions in a specific voice channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I created a command that changes voice permissions, but what I want is if the user doesn't have Manage Channel on that voice channel they can't use it. How do I do this? I know about `member.permissions.has()` but that doesn't check for permissions in the specific voice channel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`permissionsIn`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissionsIn) method would be useful here:

```js
member.permissionsIn(theVoiceChannel).has('MANAGE_CHANNELS')
```